# Android: Setting up a periodical alarm with AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In my app, I need to add a row to a database and simultaniously set up an Alarm event to repeat every day at the time specified in one of the database columns. I already have some code, but it doesent trigger the alarm event at the specified time. Here is my code:

```
public class Add_reminder extends Activity {
    AlarmManager am;
    int hours, minutes;
    REMIND_DB db;
    Calendar calendar;
    Cursor cursor;
    Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //The usual code in the beginning of onCreate

        //I load db from extended Application class as global since i use it in more
        //Activities. Ints hours and minutes is set by user interaction

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.open();
                db.insertReminder( -- parameters for database --);
                cursor = db.getAllReminders();
                cursor.moveToLast();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Add_reminder.this, ReminderAlarm.class);
                intent.putExtra("id_of_db_row", cursor.getInt(0));
                PendingIntent pi =  PendingIntent.getActivity(Add_reminder.this,
                    cursor.getInt(0), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    24*3600*1000, pi);
                db.close()
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

Database is updated correctly, but the ReminderActivity never starts on specified time. I dont know what could be wrong. I saw some example codes using BroadcastReceiver instead of starting the Activity right on with the PendingIntent, but this should work too, right? Does anyone knows what could be wrong?

My second question is if Im going to need the same instance of AlarmManager when I want to add or remove some alarms from a different Activity, or do I just declare another AlarmManager in every Activity I need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a broadcast receiver for alarms, and then start a service that does the actual work. Broadcast receivers shouldn't block the UI thread with lengthy operations (such as writing to the DB). Additionally, 'once a day' alarms might be problematic: if the user reboots the phone: registered alarms will be lost. You need to:

- save the time the alarm is supposed to run to, say, SharedPreferecnes
- re-register your alarm when the phone boots (receive the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast)
- don't use `setRepeating()` but let each alarm register the next on

Using a shorter period (1 or 2 minutes) for testing also helps.

As for the `AlarmManager` instance, it's a system service, you don't need to care about what instance you are using. Just get it using `getSystemService()`

Comment: When I looked at my phone this morning, I noticed that the desired Activity was started! Seem that the problem was the time I set for it (instead of using HOUR_OF_DAY for 24-format, I used HOUR for 12-format, so the reminder reminded itself 12 hours later). I have a block of code in my main activity that executes only once after activity is launched. Could I re-register my alarms there, using data from the database? Would it replace my alarms in case that user only restarted the app, not the phone itself? Or would it just duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: Progress :) Still, it is generally a bad idea to have activities popping up out of nowhere. As I said, use a broadcast receiver and a service. If you need user interaction, post a notification and let the user start the activity. If you use an equivalent `PendingIntent` alarms will be overwritten, not duplicated.

Comment: A great help, thank you :) I will be using a BroadcastReceiver as you said, this timing problem was just more immediate :)

Comment: why not using setRepeating? on BOOT_COMPLETED the alarm will be set, then after the first time it will continue to repeat periodically.